# Using fwrite in strange way

Tags: c, io, fwrite

If I write

```
if((fp = fopen(some_path, "wb")))
{   
    int a = 50000;
    fwrite("c",sizeof(char),a,fp);
    fclose(fp);
    fp = fopen(some_path, "rb");
    char arr[50000];
    fread(arr, sizeof(char), a, fp);
    printf("%s\n", arr);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

it prints "c" of course but the file is ~50kb

My questions are:

1. How is this actually working?
2. If I modify var a to 60000 the executable crashes, so i`m thinking about some internal buffer of fwrite. How do i get its max capacity?
3. What does fwrite() write to the file in order to get the file to ~50kb of size and still print only "c"(I was expecting some mambo-jumbo characters here)?
4. How wrong is this usage of the function, I want to write a blank file of a certain size really fast(with dummy data), would I be wrong exploiting this behaviour in order not to make a big buffer and use up memory to write "real" data but still reduce fwrite calls(I may need to write a 10 gb file for ex.)?

Comment: Tip: `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be `1`

Comment: `fread` doesn't guarantee the buffer will be NUL-terminated, so it's not safe to send the buffer to `printf "%s"`

Comment: fwrite will write what's in the string `"c"` untill `50000` chars,
although the string contains only two known chars `'c'` and `'\0'`
the fwrite will write chars from memory(**unaddressable access**)
and the reason you get the output only `c` is because the printf
is reading untill it hits the null terminator which is in this case
right after the `'c'` character, try go and open the file to see yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *How is this actually working?*

I would argue that it isn't working. You did something nonsense, and it went uncaught. The gave you the impression that it will work in the future. That's a failure.

> *If I modify var a to 60000 the executable crashes, so i`m thinking about some internal buffer of fwrite. How do i get its max capacity?*

There's no buffer. You are merely accessing whatever is in memory after the `c␀` created by `"c"`. When it crashes, it's because you've reached a memory page that can't be read (e.g. hasn't been allocated).

> *What does fwrite() write to the file in order to get the file to ~50kb of size*

Whatever happens to be in memory at the address returned by `"c"` and beyond.

> *and still print only "c"(I was expecting some mambo-jumbo characters here)?*

It doesn't print only `c`. Try something like `hexdump -C file` or `od -c file`

> *How wrong is this usage of the function*

Incredibly. It could crash for any value of `a` larger than 2.

> *I want to write a blank file of a certain size really fast(with dummy data)*

The docs for `truncate` says: "*If the file previously was shorter, it is extended, and the extended part reads as null bytes ('\0').*" So you could use the following:

```c
if (truncate(path, length)) {
   perror("truncate");
   exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Thank for the explanation, I figured that this shouldn't work, but still it did.. made me quite curious

Comment: Accessing random memory is "merely" undefined behaviour. Crashing is a possibility, but it's not the only one.